# How to add Copyright to Nuitka generated Exe

Tags: python, python-3.9, nuitka

To add copyright to nuitka generated exe

Script-

```
python -m nuitka -standalone --windows-company-name=MYcompany --windows-file-version=1.1.0 --windows-product-name=app --enable-plugin=tk-inter main.py
```

I want to know how to add copyright to the exe file generated using Nuitka

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but for me is working.
PS. This will not work for every EXE file like GoDot ones, just give it a try.

I use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to edit this stuffs. I used this **RH** when I used ***pyinstaller*** and there I had no control over metadata file, with ***nuitka*** I use it just to add that *copyright* info on the metadata.

I use the zip version of it. Just drag and drop your EXE file over the ResourceHacker.exe (or if you have installed then you can just right click your EXE and should be an option "Open using Resource Hacker").

Then you can go to *Version Info* and ad the copyright value.

[image: Add copyright]

As an hint, if you do not know the *VALUE* name you can generate an template and copy something from there and paste it over your file.

[image: Template]

After that you need to compile the changes.

[image: Compile]

And at the end you will need to save it off course.

[image: Save as]

Answer (score 0):

The following command line parameters can be used to define the executable file metadata when compiling in Nuitka:

```
--company-name=COMPANY_NAME
                    Name of the company to use in version information.
                    Defaults to unused.
--product-name=PRODUCT_NAME
                    Name of the product to use in version information.
                    Defaults to base filename of the binary.
--file-version=FILE_VERSION
                    File version to use in version information. Must be a
                    sequence of up to 4 numbers, e.g. 1.0 or 1.0.0.0, no
                    more digits are allowed, no strings are allowed.
                    Defaults to unused.
--product-version=PRODUCT_VERSION
                    Product version to use in version information. Same
                    rules as for file version. Defaults to unused.
--file-description=FILE_DESCRIPTION
                    Description of the file used in version information.
                    Windows only at this time. Defaults to binary
                    filename.
--copyright=COPYRIGHT_TEXT
                    Copyright used in version information. Windows only at
                    this time. Defaults to not present.
--trademarks=TRADEMARK_TEXT
                    Copyright used in version information. Windows only at
                    this time. Defaults to not present.
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted as correct.